# How to create a fully functional contact form within an HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a small HTML form. Basically my goal is to have the first tab to display a contact form that will unlock the rest of the form and give the user the ability to edit the contact form after submit (incase of an error) without refreshing the page and deleting the form values that display in the form. After the contact portion is submitted the values entered will display throughout the form.

https://jsfiddle.net/yq7hon4u/

```js
// Contact Form
function submitButton() {
  document.getElementById('submitButton').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('contactBar').style.display = "block";

  return false;
}

function contact() {
  var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
  var lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  document.getElementById("firstName1").textContent = firstName;
  document.getElementById("lastName1").textContent = lastName;
  document.getElementById("email1").textContent = email;
}

//Form Tabs
var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab

function showTab(n) {
  // This function will display the specified tab of the form ...
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  x[n].style.display = "block";


  if (n == 0) {
    document.getElementById("prevBtnBottom").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("prevBtnTop").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("prevBtnBottom").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("prevBtnTop").style.display = "inline";
  }
  //Form 5 displays only Previous button, Next button is disabled.
  if (n == 3) {
    document.getElementById("nextBtnBottom").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("nextBtnTop").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtnBottom").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("nextBtnTop").style.display = "inline";
  }
  fixStepIndicator(n)
}

function nextPrev(n) {
  // This function will figure out which tab to display
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
  if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
  // Hide the current tab:
  x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
  // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
  currentTab = currentTab + n;
  // if you have reached the end of the form... :
  if (currentTab >= x.length) {
    //...the form gets submitted:
    document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
    return false;
  }
  // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
  showTab(currentTab);
}

function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    // If a field is empty...
    if (y[i].value == "") {
      // add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false:
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}

function fixStepIndicator(n) {
  // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
  var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  //... and adds the "active" class to the current step:
  x[n].className += " active";
}
```

```css
/* Style the form */

#regForm {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 70%;
  min-width: 300px;
}


/* Style for Select */

select.select {
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 55%;
  Border: none;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}


/* Style for buttons */

button {
  background-color: #faa51a;
  font-size: 16px;
}


/* Hidden */

.hide {
  display: none;
}


/* Hide all steps by default: */

.tab {
  display: none;
}


/* Make circles that indicate the steps of the form: */

.step {
  height: 24px;
  width: 20px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #b8cce4;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0.5;
}


/* Mark the active step: */

.step.active {
  opacity: 1;
}


/* Mark the steps that are finished and valid: */

.step.finish {
  background-color: #b8cce4;
}


/* Used for blue background headings */

tr.blueHead {
  background-color: #b8cce4;
}


/* Resposive table */

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20);
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

table.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

table.summary {
  background-color: e9e9e9 border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}


/* Sets padding around the table cells */

th,
td {
  padding: 3px;
  /*  text-align: left;*/
}


/* Subtotal */

td.subtotal {
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* Indents table cells */

td.indent {
  text-indent: 2%;
}

img.center {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- Start of RegForm -->
<div id="tab">
  <div id="regForm">
    <br>
    <div style="float:right;">
      <button type="button" id="prevBtnTop" onclick="nextPrev(-1)"></button>
      <button type="button" id="nextBtnTop" onclick="nextPrev(1)"></button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    </head>

    <body>

      <div class="tab">
        <center>
        </center>
        <h4><u>Fill out the folowing required fields</u></h4>
        <center>
          <form action="" onsubmit="return submitButton()">
            <div id="submitButton" style="margin-bottom: -20px">
              <input id="firstName" type="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="First Name" required/>
              <input id="lastName" type="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Last Name" required/>
              <input id="email" type="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Email" required/>
              <button onclick="contact(); nextPrev(1);" value="submit">Submit</button>
              <br>
        </center>
        </div>

        <div id="contactBar" style="display:none; margin-bottom: -30px">
          <table id="contact" class="noDecor">
            <tr class="noDecor">
              <td class="noDecor"><b><span id="firstName1"></span></b></td>
              <td class="noDecor"><b><span id="lastName1"></span></b></td>
              <td class="noDecor"><b><span id="email1"></span></b></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        </form>

        <!-- A.-->

        <div class="tab">
          <table id="sectionA">
            <tr class="blueHead">
              <th colspan="3"><b>Section A </b></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <table id="table1">
            <tr>
              <td>Question 1:</td>
              <td>
                <select>
                  <option value="0">0</option>
                  <option value="1">1</option>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Question 2:</td>
              <td>
                <select>
                  <option value="0">0</option>
                  <option value="1">1</option>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <br>
        </div>

        <!-- B. -->

        <div class="tab">
          <table id="sectionB">
            <tr class="blueHead">
              <th colspan="3"><b>Section B </b></th>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <table id="table2">
            <tr>
              <td>Question 3:</td>
              <td>
                <select>
                  <option value="0">0</option>
                  <option value="1">1</option>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Question 4:</td>
              <td>
                <select>
                  <option value="0">0</option>
                  <option value="1">1</option>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <br>
        </div>

        <!-- C. -->

        <div class="tab">
          <table id="sectionC">
            <tr class="blueHead">
              <th colspan="3"><b>Section C </b></th>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <table id="table3">
            <tr>
              <td>Question 5:</td>
              <td>
                <select>
                  <option value="0">0</option>
                  <option value="1">1</option>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Question 6:</td>
              <td>
                <select>
                  <option value="0">0</option>
                  <option value="1">1</option>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <br>
        </div>


        <!-- Next and Previous buttons -->
        <div style="float:right;">
          <button type="button" id="prevBtnBottom" onclick="nextPrev(-1)"></button>
          <button type="button" id="nextBtnBottom" onclick="nextPrev(1)"></button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
        <span class="step"><b>S</a></span>
        <span class="step">A</span>
        <span class="step">B</span>
        <span class="step">C</span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is, specifically?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. My question is how can I create the ability for a user to edit my contact form portion, incase a mistake is made and would need to revert back to make changes while at the same time not refreshing the page so that values won't be deleted.

Comment: I don't understand. Your code seems to already have the ability to do that.

Comment: Hi Thanks. I would like to be able to edit the contact form after I click submit.

Comment: input type="reset"? ctrl-z?